# Ionic 4. Alternative to NavParams

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic 4. It does not accept to receive data using navparams.
Here is my sender page method:

```
  //private route:Router
  gotoFinalView(intent) {
    this.route.navigateByUrl(`${intent}`, this.destination);
  }
```

Receiver page line;

```
  //private navParams:NavParams  
  this.destination = navParams.data;
```

What is the right approach to doing this in ionic 4. I am also uncertain whether gotoFinalView method is valid.

Comment: Which service is this.route ? Why are you don't using NavController?

Comment: private route:Router

Comment: chick this topic https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-navigate-in-ionic-4/136579/5 it could have a clue

Answer (score 5):

This is how I solved my problem:

**I created a Service with a setter and getter methods as;**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class MasterDetailService {
  private destn: any;
  constructor() {}

  public setDestn(destn) {
    this.destn = destn;
  }

  getDestn() {
    return this.destn;
  }
}
```

**Injected the Service and NavController in the first page and used it as;**

```
  gotoFinalView(destn) {
    this.masterDetailService.setDestn(destn);
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward("destn-page");
  }
```

**Extracted the data at the final page by;**

```
constructor(
    private masterDetailService: MasterDetailService
  ) {
    this.destination = this.masterDetailService.getDestn();
  }
```

Comment: And without a service? ... Maybe `router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state` You have to differ between url query parameter and body parameter (not in the url)

Comment: Ionic 4 uses the Angular router. Use `ActivatedRoute` to pass parameters to other pages. No need to create a service just for this.

Answer (score 5):

This is the efficient way to solve your problem
user Angular Routers concepts in your application.
just declare your router like the following

Your app routing module like the following

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ViewComponent} from "./crud/view/view.component";
import {CreateComponent} from "./crud/create/create.component";  
import {UpdateComponent} from "./crud/update/update.component";
import {ReadComponent} from "./crud/read/read.component";

const routes: Routes = [
{path: '', component: ViewComponent},
{path: 'create', component: CreateComponent},
{path: 'update/:id', component: UpdateComponent},
{path: 'view/:id', component: ReadComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

:id is the parameter what i want to send to that page.

```
 this.router.navigate([link + '/' + id]);
```

share your parameter like this in your first page.

In your second page inject the activated route using DI(Dependency Injection)

```
constructor(private actRoute: ActivatedRoute)
```

Then Get your parameters using the following code

```
this.productID = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
```

This is the simple way. You can send multiple parameter at a time.

```
{path: 'update/:id/:name/:price', component: UpdateComponent}
```

and get those parameters like the following

```
this.productID = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
this.productName = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['name'];
this.productPrice = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

While Routing you can write like this:

```
this.router.navigate(["/payment-details",{
  prev_vehicle_type: this.vehicle_type,
      prev_amt: this.amt,
      prev_journey:this.whichj
}]);
```

To get this parameters on the next page you can write:

```
constructor(
public router: Router,
public activateroute: ActivatedRoute){
this.activateroute.params.subscribe((data: any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.vehicle_type = data.prev_vehicle_type;
  this.amt = data.prev_amt;
  this.whichj = data.prev_journey;

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic 4 navigation with params

sender page
1. import the following

```
import {NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
import { NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
```

2. constructor(private navCtrl:NavController)
3. sender page

gotonextPage()

```
gotonextPage()
{
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          state: {
            user: 'name',
            parms:Params
          }
        };
        this.navCtrl.navigateForward('pageurl',navigationExtras);
}
```

4.Receiver Page

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router)
{
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
    this.navParams = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.parms;
  }});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data with **Router** service and extract with global variable, **history**

**//sender component**

```
  // private router: Router
  nextPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['history'],
      { state: [{ name: "covid-19", origin: "china" },{ name: "ebola", origin: "us" }] }
    )
  }
```

**//receiver page**

```
  ngOnInit() {
  let data = history.state;
  console.log("data-->",data);
// ** data** 
//0:{name: "covid-19", origin: "china"} 1: {name: "ebola", origin: "us"} navigationId: 2
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The item, icon and title variables you want to send should be written in the state in this way.

```
this.nav.navigateForward('/myUrl', {
        state: {
          'items': this.substances,
          'icon': ICONS.substance,
          'title': 'Etken Maddeler'
        }
      });
```

We take incoming variables this way.

```
//receive
constructor(
      protected route: ActivatedRoute,
      protected router: Router,
  ) {
    this.selectedItem = null;
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let st = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
      if (st) {
        this.selectedItem = st.items;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: How is that way?

Answer (score 0):

Very very simply, you can do something like this:

In the "calling screen" :

```
this.router.navigate(['url', {model: JSON.stringify(myCustomObject)}])
```

In the "called screen" :

```
this.myvar = JSON.parse(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('model')
```

Et voilà !

Comment: What if I need to send a function? I cannot stringify/parse it.

Answer (score -1):

```
//in home.ts
import{ Router,ActivatedRoute, NavigationExtras }         from '@angular/router';
getProductStatics(productObject : any) {
    var object1 = {
            id: productObject, 
        }
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {state : {object: 
    JSON.stringify(object1)}};
    this.router.navigate(["/product-statics"], navigationExtras);
}
//in product-statics.ts

import{ Router,ActivatedRoute,NavigationExtras }         from '@angular/router';
if(self.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state) {
                 var object1 
       =  this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.object;
                var object  = JSON.parse(object1);
          var newObjectData    = object.id;      
 }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.