# Ionic 4 Angular 7 - passing object/data to another page

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7, angular-router, ionic4

I would like to pass a JSON object to another page. What I've tried is to pass the JSON string using Angular router `ActivatedRoute` like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['details', details]);
```

and then retrieve it like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
  }


ngOnInit() {

  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(extras => {
     console.log(extras);
     this.JSONObject = extras;
  });

}
```

It is possible to do it this way but what happened was the nested JSON objects becomes inaccessible. It turns into this string:

```
"[object Object]"
```

The stringified JSON object is fine and accessible before I pass it. Another problem is that it appends the JSON string to the url so it doesn't look that nice. From what I read as well, it is not a good practice to pass something more than just an `id` this way.

I am thinking of something like passing objects as intent extras between activities in Android. I've searched the documentations, forums, and previous stackoverflow questions but I didn't found any solution that enables me to achieve this. Is there any other way of passing objects between pages using Angular router in Ionic4?

Comment: Have you tried using rxjs Subject or a shared service?

Comment: @HasilT Nope, I haven't. I'm reading on them now. They're quite new to me

Comment: @tyn Sit and learn about Services.
Easiest and simplest way to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Talg123 I did and it solved my problem! :D

Comment: @tyn Good job my friend :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved it using a service with a simple setter and getter just like in this question that I later found:

> [Ionic 4. Alternative to NavParams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53522324/ionic-4-alternative-to-navparams)

First, I create a service with setter & getter:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavExtrasService {

    extras: any;

      constructor() { }

      public setExtras(data){
        this.extras = data;
      }

      public getExtras(){
        return this.extras;
      }
    }
```

Let's say I'm navigating from page A to page B, in page A:

```
this.navExtras.setExtras(extras)
this.router.navigateByUrl('page-b');
```

Then in Page B, I retrieve the extras this way:

```
this.location = navExtras.getExtras();
```

It works so far although I'm still not sure if there are better ways to do it..

Comment: navExtras.getExtras();  .. this function is not calling

Comment: @RageshDAntony can you provide a more detailed description?